# QT Creator: undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

I am building a Unit-Test using [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial1.html). However, when compiling my code I get these two errors:

> undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'.
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a main function where you create a qapplication? There's a good example [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/mainwindows-application.html)

You can also get that error when you're creating a DOS executable instead of a Windows GUI executable. It's looking for winmain() not main(),

Comment: I was creating a "Qt Gui Application" and calling my function from the MainWindow.cpp after including the header file that contains the function declaration. By doing so, I don't have to create a separate main function, do I ?. However, I was interesting in what you said about the DOS executable. it is clear that I am building a Gui application and not stand-alone ".exe" file, so why it is not compiling ?

another thing, I created a new project: Qt Unit Test. and now it is working fine. so, I can't build my own test unit function instead I should create a qt unit test project, is that it ?

Comment: You may have included the header file, which defines the main function, but doesn't instantiate it. When it runs the compiler to build the application exe file does it include the cpp file that contains your main? Just including the header file isn't enough.

Comment: Now, it is working fine even with the "Qt Gui Application". what I did is I wrote in the "main.cpp" this function `QTest::qExec(&testString, argc, argv);` to execute my unit-test. But what I used to do before is calling my test-function directly without creating an object and I was calling it from the wrong file (i.e.: MainWindow.cpp) again without calling the QTest::qExec. so it works now. but honestly I don't follow the errors of the Qt Unit Test !!!

Comment: Glad you made progress. If you feel your question was answered correctly please mark the answer as the correct one. That helps others when they might have the same issue.